# Java generics: Functional-like max()

Tags: java, generics

Function abstraction:

```
  public abstract class Function<X, Y> {     
      abstract Y apply(X x);      
  }
```

`max` method implementation

```
public static <V extends Comparable<V>> Function<List<V>, V> max() {

    return new Function<List<V>, V>() {
        @Override
        public V apply(List<V> list) {
            return Collections.max(list);
        }
    };
}
```

And usage (how it should look like)

```
Date result = max().apply(datesList);
```

But I get this error and don't understand why it requires `Object`

```
incompatible types; inferred type argument(s) java.lang.Object do not conform to bounds of type variable(s) V
found   : <V>project.Function<java.util.List<V>,V>
required: java.lang.Object
```

I have read big amount of similar QA but didn't get how to fix this.
Thanks.

Comment: FYI, your `Function` type looks like a good place to use an [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).

Comment: I agree with Taymon, I would make that an interface instead of an abstract class. Note that [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) already has a `Function` interface that's exactly the same.

Comment: @Taymon Thanks for suggestion, but actually I have more methods in this class. For example:
public <Z> Function<X, Z> then(Function<Y, Z> second){...}

Comment: Google Guava also has a class `Functions` with utility methods to compose functions, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Java has a very limited type inference. If you write this:

```
Date result = max().apply(datesList);
```

it is not sophisticated enough to infer the type parameter of the `max()` method, `V`, so it takes `java.lang.Object` instead. You could try this:

```
Function<List<Date>, Date> fn = max();
Date result = fn.apply(dates);
```

Or, if you want to write it in one line, you could do the following, assuming that your `max()` method is defined in a class named `Example`:

```
Date result = Example.<Date>max().apply(dates);
```

Comment: I now understand that this was not my fault, but Java type inference limitations. Thanks !